# array join function not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, fromcharcode

for some reason Im not able to see why my array join method wont work. here's the quick code for review:

```
function rot13(str) { // LBH QVQ VG!
  var strAry = str.split('');

  var transformed = strAry.map(function(val){

    if(val === " ") return " ";
    else{
      var code = val.charCodeAt(0);
      return  String.fromCharCode(code-13);
    }
  });
  transformed.join('');
 console.log(transformed);
  return transformed;
}

// Change the inputs below to test
rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC");
```

The idea is to pass in the string and it will be converted to a readable code string, but the join is not working. Also, a few of the digits are not converting properly not sure why, bonus points for that one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't save the result returned of `.join()`

```
transformed = transformed.join('');
```

or

```
return transformed.join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this it will work

```
function rot13(str) { 
// LBH QVQ VG!
  var strAry = str.split('');

  var transformed = strAry.map(function(val){

    if(val === " ") return " ";
    else{
      var code = val.charCodeAt(0);
      return  String.fromCharCode(code-13);
    }
  });
  transformed = transformed.join('');
 console.log(transformed);
  return transformed;
}
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/w3npo8vs/)

Comment: Instead of saying "_Replace this it will work_" you should explain what you changed and why.